# Add a last cell to UItableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a **UITableView** whose datasource is a **NSMutableArray**. The array consists of a set of objects. All the cells are displayed in proper order.

Now I want to know how to display a last cell always with some text alone which is not there in the datasource array.

I hope i am clear enough :)

**EDIT :----------**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
     //+1 to add the last extra row
     return [appDelegate.list count]+1;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

NSUInteger index=[indexPath row];

 if(index ==([appDelegate.list count]+1)) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"extra cell"];    
    }else{
    Item *i = (Item *) [appDelegate.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d %@)",i.iName, i.iQty,i.iUnit];
    }
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

but i get the NSMutableArray out of bounds exception.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Can a header or footer work for you in this case?

Comment: @Nitish: ahh...never thought of that. Can a footer be made clickable ?
if so how?

Comment: No, you can't click a footer. I thought you did'nt want to click the cell just having some text.

Comment: You can make a footer clickable by having custom view for it.  Implement the following delegate method 

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the value you are checking against index. The `list` has count objects indexed 0 to count - 1. So you must check against `count` and not `count + 1`. As it is now, the request for `count`th row is entering the `else` section. There is no object at `count` in the `list` array. So you are getting the error. This is the modification.

```
if(index == [appDelegate.list count] ) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"extra cell"];    
}else{
    Item *i = (Item *) [appDelegate.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d %@)",i.iName, i.iQty,i.iUnit];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return [your_array count] + 1;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
      reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
   }

   NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
   if (row == [your_array count])
   {
      cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text"];
   }
   else
   {
      cell.textLabel.text = your array object text;
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: can yu check my edit ? I tried the same thing..but getting array out of bounds error

Comment: I have remove + 1 from if condition.

Answer (score 1):

in `numberOfRowInSection` return `number of rows = your array count +1` then in Cell for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for indexPath.row if it is equla to your array `count +1` then create cell that you want to add at last.