# Add One More Cell to tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My issue is similar what this guy had:

[Add a last cell to UItableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068144/add-a-last-cell-to-uitableview)

In fact I'm using the same method which got selected in that question, here's the code snippet:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
    return [array count] + 1;
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    NSUInteger rowN = [indexPath row];

    if (rowN == [array count]) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text"];

    } else {

    TFHppleElement* pCell = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pCell content]];

    }

    return cell;    
}
```

Now, I'm getting exception error: `*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]`.

What could be the issue? From the error, it looks like that `[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is trying to access 6th index of the array which doesn't exist but why it is trying to access 6th index when I have the code in `else` condition?

Comment: why do you have the "+1" in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method up there? What happens when you change `if (rowN == [array count])` to `if (rowN >= [array count])` ??

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I believe he wants to add an extra row after the rows from the array, that would be the +1

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Same result. :(

Comment: One more thing to make sure that the problem is here, comment out the 2 rows in the `else { }` statement. If you still get the exception the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Arrays start at element 0, try to log out your indexPath.row and your [array count].

Comment: One remark, besides the issue at hand - autorelease the freshly created UITableViewCells - you're leaking them in this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Change this row:

```
NSUInteger rowN = [indexPath row];
```

to:

```
NSUInteger rowN = indexPath.row;
```

Or use just the `indexPath.row` instead of the `rowN` in the `if` condition

Comment: Both variants are semantically equivalent... (Your variant is, of course, cleaner, but does most likely not solve the actual problem.)

Comment: Ah! found the solution actually, I wasn't using if condition in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method and `objectAtIndex` was trying to access 6th index of the array. Sorry for bothering guys. Up vote for you for wasting time in my useless question.

Comment: @mrueg Thanks for pointing this out. Then this shouldn't be the problem, but still looks for me, that the problem is around the if condition (if it is really in this function)

Comment: @OhhMee I think you should add your solution as an answer and accept it