# UITextField bottom of screen on UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitableview

I am trying to place a `UITextField` at the bottom of a `UITableViewController`.

And once you touch the `textField`, the keyboard comes up.

I first tried to simply place the `textField` on the last cell of the `tableview`, But I couldn't even get that to work. 
I am so what new to Objective-C, so i don't know if my question is confusing.

here is an image to help understand what it is exactly that i am trying to do.
http://icdn9.digitaltrends.com/image/instatag-11-340x504.jpg

the commenting section of instagram is probably the best example i can give.

Comment: What didn't work when you added it to the last cell?

Comment: @wain i used the example in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068144/add-a-last-cell-to-uitableview) do you happen to know of a different way? or even a tutorial on how to properly do this?

Comment: That doesn't tell us what problem you had specifically. I'd suggest using a footer view instead of the last cell, but that won't necessarily help you much if your problem is keyboard handling for example...

Comment: try to add Search bar or textfield in footer of UITableView.It will work. I have done the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may meet your needs:https://github.com/songfrank/DAKeyboardControl

Here is [Video demonstration on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6GLro0cyDU)